Как типизировать фунцкию, которая принимает массив кортежей, а возвращает массив строк в typescript
Есть функция, которая принимает массив массивов пользователей и возвращает массив имен пользователей, которые подходят под условия фильтрации. Подскажите, как правильно ее типизировать, так как ts выдает ошибку
type TUser = [string, number, boolean][];
const users: TUser = [
  ["Alice", 25, true],
  ["Bob", 30, false],
  ["Charlie", 22, true],
  ["David", 27, true],
  ["Eve", 20, false],
  ["Fanny", 29, true],
  ["George", 67, true],
];

function filterAndSortUsers(arr: TUser): string[] {
  let filtArr: TUser = arr.filter((item) => item[1] >= 25 && item[2] === true);
  let sortedArr: TUser= filtArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  let newArr: string[] = sortedArr.map((el) => el.splice(0, 1)).flat();

  return newArr;
}

Текст ошибки: Тип "(string | number | boolean)[]" не может быть назначен для типа "string[]".
Тип "string | number | boolean" не может быть назначен для типа "string".
Тип "number" не может быть назначен для типа "string".

Добавьте саму ошибку в вопрос

заменить на el[0]

@Grundy Не поможет скорее всего. Вангую, что используется старый TS, который метода flat не знает и надо просто настроить tsconfig - по крайней мере в песочнице ровно так ошибка починилась

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=10&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgqgZwgJygXigbQHYEMC2EAXFAsMgJbYDmANFLtcVNgK74BGK9FCAgthDAAFlWokOAe0kAbCLmwBdANwAoVQDNW2AMbAKk7FA0UZwFAIAmAZUnJgiFAgAUuZMhLwkyTIoCUno4+AAyKvlAA3qpQUDqGZMamwHzu6Azu0TFQAHQmZijOzhTm+H7oAHxQxRD4mACMilDlGABMAKxQAGSdVSWYLY1oQ1DkrBB+mTHZCHbAhbj0HGVola71jQC0UBzrfn5qmXHYCXiE-KkYecnu2fi4YIWYLATQ-hXPhPvqMcgQwKzIIynCDnZBqAC+6iOCVY3gQgW84QwmEymAARHwZBQdBA0fR2vRRhBFLRUWiAEKSDh4qAAZmC9A0uBkSBJZIAwsI3FjcfiWoTkGM2TF0QARXAANwolhpLQA7AKhaSRWiAKIS3lQFoM4zM1nKrBogBiCkEsoAnIriQb0QBxCB2Jg0gBsCpGgutqhUUPisgg2RkkmoziuFmwNlmQRcsKce2UQA

Спасибо, попробую

@SwaD, поможет, я попробовал. slice дает массив, просто не может вывести что тип элементов будет только string - поэтому пишет сводный тип для всех трех элементов. когда берешь конкретный элемент - тип просто выводится

let newArr: string[] = sortedArr.map(el => el[0]); - так не получить массив имен?

.splice - это метод массива, а не tuple. Поэтому он не может вывести тип результата основываясь на переданных параметрах. Вместо этого выводится общий тип элементов: string | number | boolean.
Для решения нужно

либо не использовать .splice, а выбирать конкретный элемент, например el[0] - в этом случае, корректно вычисляется тип возвращаемый .map

либо явно подсказать typescript какой тип ожидается, например с помощью as:
el.splice(0, 1) as [string]


